# PHP: how to used a class function?

Tags: php, class, object

I'm quite new and having some trial and test creating a class and objects.

Here's my script:

```
<?php
class testingm 
{
private $t;        
public function __construct($file) 
{
$this->t = fopen($file, 'rb')
}      
}

$test = new testingm;
$s = new file($_GET['n']);
?>
```

the script says

Warning: Missing argument 1 for testingm::__construct(), called in

how can i provide a value for the $file variable? can someone guide me?

Comment: 'try' is reserved key word. so give your class a different name. then print $_GET using print_r($_GET). Also, why don't you provide a file path to file(). e.g. file('/path/to/file.txt') for test purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$test = new testingm($_GET['n']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your [constructor method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) `__construct($file)` requires 1 parameter, `$file`, which needs to be supplied. The constructor method is called when you instantiate an object using the class with `new`.

To do this in your example, pass in the file name when you instantiate your object with `new`. For example:

```
$file = $_GET['n'];
$test = new testingm($file);
```

The PHP docs have more information on [function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) for passing parameters to methods.

Comment: @Grokify close brackets